# How to get first and the last child element of an xml element in perl

Tags: xml, perl

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

The answer should be to and body when the element name is given as node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open data.xml ;
ls (/note/*[1] | /note/*[last()]) ;
```